# Ubuntu recognize my hard drive as “ FREE Disk ”

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I've bought a new laptop ( TOSHIBA C55D-A-13Q ) and it had Windows 8 64-bit pre-installed .

I tried to install Ubuntu alongside it but it doesnt work so i've installed windows 7 64-bit instead of it in LEGACY MODE ( as I want to keep a Windows version alongside Ubuntu and I heard that EFI is quite difficult to get linux through it )

However, when I try to install Ubuntu now it doesn't recognize my existing Windows 7 OS !!

It shows that i have a "FREE DISK of 100% unallocated space".

So the only option is to use ubuntu all over the disk but I don't want that ...

Also, when I try the LiveCD version , it doesn't recognize my WIFI card ( it seems that there is no driver installed for it ) ..

I am trying to install Ubuntu version 13.10

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify _who_ shows the 100% free disk? When is this shown? Perhaps a screenshot? Does this laptop have a single hard drive or two? The WiFi is a different issue, please ask a separate question about that.

Comment: @Luciano33: Don't be sorry, just close one of the two. I'd say you should close this one, as your question seems Ubuntu specific, and [Ubuntu questions belong on the Ubuntu SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @terdon i only have 1 hard drive , i have attached a screenshot as requested

Comment: @WarrenYoung i've closed the question on askubuntu.

Comment: Umm... OK. Are you 100% sure you have a Windows installation there? Can you actually boot into Windows? It does indeed look like an empty drive. If you _can_ boot into Windows, then it sounds like a bug in the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: @terdon yes i have windows 7 64-bits installed here and im using it daily and for the moment too to post this question.. any idea how to fix this ? to precise i'm using USB flashdisk to boot the installation disk

Comment: The "flashdisk" is a 750G one right? There are no other drives shown if you click on the drop-down menu in the screenshot you show?

Comment: @terdon the flashdisk is only 16Gb . the 750Gb one is my hard drive. there is nothing shown expect what in the screenshot

Comment: Yes, I didn't think so but you never know. OK, one last thing to try is to boot into the live session (Click on "Try Ubuntu"), then open a terminal and run `sudo parted -l` and add the output to your question. That will show us the partitions available and perhaps explain why you get this problem. Alternatively, you could use Windows tools to create an empty partition and then try and install Ubuntu again.

Comment: @terdon, i've created an empty partition yesterday and it didn't work neither . i will reboot my pc on ubuntu live session and will take a screenshot right now( for sudo parted -l )

Comment: OK, don't take a screenshot, just paste the output directly into your question [using a code block](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: If you pull down the list showing `/dev/sda` right now, is there another storage medium available? Perhaps there is a `/dev/sdb`, and Windows is installed there?

Comment: @WarrenYoung No there is only the one shown there /dev/sda . i only have 1 HARD DRIVE ...

Comment: @terdon when i try to option " Try ubuntu " it doesn't work due to graphical problem  they said....